# Distributions.jl do not accept my (non positive definite) covariance function (while numpy does)

Tags: numpy, julia, linear-algebra, normal-distribution

I'm trying to implement Gaussian Processes (GPs) in Julia following [krasserm](http://krasserm.github.io/2018/03/19/gaussian-processes/).

The numpy implementation works like a charm:

```py
import numpy as np

def kernel(X1, X2, l=1.0, sigma_f=1.0):
    ''' Isotropic squared exponential kernel. Computes a covariance matrix from points in X1 and X2. Args: X1: Array of m points (m x d). X2: Array of n points (n x d). Returns: Covariance matrix (m x n). '''
    sqdist = np.sum(X1**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(X2**2, 1) - 2 * np.dot(X1, X2.T)
    return sigma_f**2 * np.exp(-0.5 / l**2 * sqdist)

X = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1).reshape(-1, 1)

mu = np.zeros(X.shape)
cov = kernel(X, X)

samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu.ravel(), cov, 3)
```

While I have an error for creating a multivariate normal using Distributions.jl.

Here what I have tried:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Distributions

function kernel(x₁, x₂; l=1.0, σ=1.0)
    t₁ = sum(x₁.^2, dims=2)
    t₂ = sum(x₂.^2, dims=2)
    t₃ = 2*x₁*x₂'
    t = (t₁ .+ t₂') - t₃
    return σ^2 * exp.(-0.5/l^2 * t)
end

x = -1:0.1:0.9
μ = zeros(length(x))
σ = kernel(x, x)
D = MvNormal(μ, σ)
```

The problem seems that my covariance is not positive (semi)definite.

Julia:

```
σ
20×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0       0.995012  0.980199  0.955997  …  0.235746  0.197899  0.164474
 0.995012  1.0       0.995012  0.980199     0.278037  0.235746  0.197899
 0.980199  0.995012  1.0       0.995012     0.324652  0.278037  0.235746
 0.955997  0.980199  0.995012  1.0          0.375311  0.324652  0.278037
 0.923116  0.955997  0.980199  0.995012     0.429557  0.375311  0.324652
 0.882497  0.923116  0.955997  0.980199  …  0.486752  0.429557  0.375311
 0.83527   0.882497  0.923116  0.955997     0.546074  0.486752  0.429557
 0.782705  0.83527   0.882497  0.923116     0.606531  0.546074  0.486752
 0.726149  0.782705  0.83527   0.882497     0.666977  0.606531  0.546074
 0.666977  0.726149  0.782705  0.83527      0.726149  0.666977  0.606531
 0.606531  0.666977  0.726149  0.782705  …  0.782705  0.726149  0.666977
 0.546074  0.606531  0.666977  0.726149     0.83527   0.782705  0.726149
 0.486752  0.546074  0.606531  0.666977     0.882497  0.83527   0.782705
 0.429557  0.486752  0.546074  0.606531     0.923116  0.882497  0.83527 
 0.375311  0.429557  0.486752  0.546074     0.955997  0.923116  0.882497
 0.324652  0.375311  0.429557  0.486752  …  0.980199  0.955997  0.923116
 0.278037  0.324652  0.375311  0.429557     0.995012  0.980199  0.955997
 0.235746  0.278037  0.324652  0.375311     1.0       0.995012  0.980199
 0.197899  0.235746  0.278037  0.324652     0.995012  1.0       0.995012
 0.164474  0.197899  0.235746  0.278037     0.980199  0.995012  1.0
```

python:

```py
>>> cov
array([[1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635,
        0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681,
        0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226, 0.42955736, 0.3753111 ,
        0.32465247, 0.2780373 , 0.23574608, 0.1978987 , 0.16447446],
       [0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748,
        0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904,
        0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226, 0.42955736,
        0.3753111 , 0.32465247, 0.2780373 , 0.23574608, 0.1978987 ],
       [0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867,
        0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454,
        0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226,
        0.42955736, 0.3753111 , 0.32465247, 0.2780373 , 0.23574608],
       [0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248,
        0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021,
        0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443,
        0.48675226, 0.42955736, 0.3753111 , 0.32465247, 0.2780373 ],
       [0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        ,
        0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 ,
        0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066,
        0.54607443, 0.48675226, 0.42955736, 0.3753111 , 0.32465247],
       [0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248,
        1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635,
        0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681,
        0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226, 0.42955736, 0.3753111 ],
       [0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867,
        0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748,
        0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904,
        0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226, 0.42955736],
       [0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748,
        0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867,
        0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454,
        0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443, 0.48675226],
       [0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635,
        0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248,
        0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021,
        0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066, 0.54607443],
       [0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 ,
        0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        ,
        0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 ,
        0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681, 0.60653066],
       [0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021,
        0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248,
        1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635,
        0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904, 0.66697681],
       [0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454,
        0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867,
        0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748,
        0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454, 0.72614904],
       [0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904,
        0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748,
        0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867,
        0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021, 0.78270454],
       [0.42955736, 0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681,
        0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635,
        0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248,
        0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 , 0.83527021],
       [0.3753111 , 0.42955736, 0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066,
        0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 ,
        0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        ,
        0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635, 0.8824969 ],
       [0.32465247, 0.3753111 , 0.42955736, 0.48675226, 0.54607443,
        0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021,
        0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248,
        1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748, 0.92311635],
       [0.2780373 , 0.32465247, 0.3753111 , 0.42955736, 0.48675226,
        0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454,
        0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867,
        0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867, 0.95599748],
       [0.23574608, 0.2780373 , 0.32465247, 0.3753111 , 0.42955736,
        0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681, 0.72614904,
        0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635, 0.95599748,
        0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248, 0.98019867],
       [0.1978987 , 0.23574608, 0.2780373 , 0.32465247, 0.3753111 ,
        0.42955736, 0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066, 0.66697681,
        0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 , 0.92311635,
        0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        , 0.99501248],
       [0.16447446, 0.1978987 , 0.23574608, 0.2780373 , 0.32465247,
        0.3753111 , 0.42955736, 0.48675226, 0.54607443, 0.60653066,
        0.66697681, 0.72614904, 0.78270454, 0.83527021, 0.8824969 ,
        0.92311635, 0.95599748, 0.98019867, 0.99501248, 1.        ]])
```

Numpy seems to accept it without complains but MvNormal says:

```
PosDefException: matrix is not Hermitian; Cholesky factorization failed.
```

or

```
PosDefException: matrix is not positive definite; Cholesky factorization failed.
```

As it seems that it can be a problem of floating points precision, I have tried [sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600815/mvnormal-error-with-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix) using:

```
σ = σ + maximum([0.0, -minimum(eigvals(σ))])*I
D = MvNormal(μ, σ)
```

which should make the matrix positive definite, without success.

Solution [sol1](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multivariate-normal-with-positive-semi-definite-covariance-matrix/3029/13) or a combination of [sol1](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multivariate-normal-with-positive-semi-definite-covariance-matrix/3029/13) and [sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600815/mvnormal-error-with-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix) did not work either:

```
σ = Symmetric(σ)
D = MvNormal(σ.data)
```

I also tried as in [sol3](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-force-a-matrix-to-be-hermitian/18479) to make it Hermitian when needed:

```
D = MvNormal(Matrix(Hermitian(σ)))
```

Do you have any insight of what should I do?

---

After further tests, it seems that

```
σ = σ + 0.00000000001*I
D = MvNormal(σ)
```

works, but I find this solution really awful, why does it even work ?

Comment: It seems that numpy is 'sloppy' here, while Julia is strict. The numpy doc says that the cov matrix should be posdef, but does not enforce it. This appears to work: `σ + max(0, -2minimum(eigvals(σ))) * I`.

Comment: BTW, wrapping a matrix in `Symmetric` and then reading the `.data` field will just undo the symmetry (`.data` is just the original underlying matrix). Just use the output of `Symmetric(σ)` directly (even though it won't help you make your matrix posdef this time).

Comment: Actually, it does not seem to work reliably just multiplying the smallest eigenvalue by -2. You may have to try a slightly larger scaling. Also, you could use `eigmin(σ)` instead of `minimum(eigvals(σ))`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, at the moment I'm changing manually the scaling of the multiplying value of the identity depending on the size of x.. ```σ = σ + 0.00000000001*I``` Not the best approach but doing this or scaling by the minimal eigen value  is almost the same but require less computations.. I tried to send directly Symmetric(sigma) to a MvNormal but it raised an error I will try again this tomorrow. Nevertheless, I would be interested in the rationale of using the minimal eigenvalue, it doesn't make sense to me right now.

Comment: A symmetric matrix is positive semi-definite if the smallest eigenvalue is >= 0. The eigenvalues of the matrix `M + a*I` is equal to the eigenvalues of `M` plus the value `a`. So if you want to turn all the eigenvalues non-negative, you add `a*I` to `M` where `a` is equal to or bigger then the -1 times the most negative eigenvalue. Of course, you can then  get numerical roundoff errors, to *still* end up with negative values, so it's useful to multiply it by some sufficiently large factor.

Comment: Very nice, this makes sense, thanks! I've changed my code with ```eigmin``` and I needed to warp Symmetric struct into hermitian matrices to make them play nicely with MvNormal. At the moment I'm using '5' as bigger constant, however, I think I will make it dynamic depending on the exponent of the eigenvalue. I also discovered ```UniformScaling``` https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html#LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling during the process :)

Comment: @DNF Would you mind adding the solution from the comments as an answer below? I'm trying to get old "unanswered" Julia questions to be answered, for better visibility.  But I don't have the domain knowledge in this case, to transfer the suggestions and explanation into a coherent answer.