# Cannot fit a MvNormal distribution with Distributions.jl. ERROR: PosDefException: matrix is not positive definite; Cholesky factorization failed

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, normal-distribution

I'm trying to fit an `MvNormal` distribution to a matrix of spectral data, but I am getting the following error:

```
Distributions.fit(MvNormal, myMatrix)

> ERROR: PosDefException: matrix is not positive definite; Cholesky factorization failed.
```

`myMatrix` consists of readings of absorbance (one column per item) at many consecutive wavenumbers (rows). It is not a square matrix and hence it cannot be positive definite.

From what I have seen online, lots of people report error messages of various methods failing at the Cholesky factorisation step in Julia. I understand that this comes from it being more strict than other languages at checking that the PD criterion is met when needed.

Other people (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559589/distributions-jl-do-not-accept-my-non-positive-definite-covariance-function-w), for example) have managed to solve this issue by making slight changes to the sigma parameter when stating a distribution. However, since I am not creating a distribution in terms of its parameters, but fitting it to a matrix, I am uncertain on what to do.

I would deeply appreciate any suggestions on

- how I could try and make my matrix appropriate for Cholesky factorisation, or
- fit a multivariate normal distribution to my data using any other method or package.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, I believe this error message is highly misleading, or possibly a bug.

`fit` isn't expecting `myMatrix` to be positive definite, in fact it shouldn't even be a square matrix.

`fit` expects the second argument to be a `n` by `S` matrix where `n` are the number of dimensions, and `S` is the number of samples you are fitting against.
The error message regarding positive definitve matrices and positive definite problems just comes from the math it performs during fitting a underdetermined system. Under normal circumstances, we would expect `S` to be much greater than `n`.

Example:

```
# Construct samples:
C = [0.2 0; 0.1 0.3]
mean = [2.,3.]
d = MvNormal(mean, C)
samples = rand(d, 100) # This is your input data, in this case a 2x100 matrix.

# Fitting:
d_fit = Distributions.fit(MvNormal, samples)
```

Comparing `d` and `d_fit`, I see a pretty good match, and it gets better with the number of samples.

In summary: You probably just need more (unique) samples to fit against.